About redshift and distant objects observation
I did a few Time&Length dilation factor calculations. This is for a distant clock away from any field and a clock on Earth on the equator with the moon passing over clock coordinates, the factors are :









Moon
0,999 999 999 998 118


Earth
0,999 999 999 302 670


Sun
0,999 999 985 194 619


Milky Way
0,999 991 124 836 797


Andromeda
0,999 999 924 724 351 (gravitational only)






Relative Product
0,999 991 034 057 362



If I didn’t do any mistake, interestingly the Sun and Andromeda dilation factors are in the same range and the Milky way has the main influence on the Earth clock. We could add other planets, correct values considering our galaxy masses distribution, add Fermi bubbles and progressively add all visible matter in the universe to get a global time dilation relative factor for an Earth clock.
For the sake of personal comprehension I created the animation here to illustrate various redshifts on distant observed objects. Every described case has 3 info lines on its scale : a metric factor, a distance from the object to the observer and a speed ratio (or geometric speed) or speed when it is null. Redshift is schematically illustrated with bigger red glow. Time is 10 seconds for 10^10 years.
First case is when there is no redshift, when everything is hypothetically static. Second case describes how strong redshift would be for unitarily distant objects moving at the same constant proper speed. Third is what could theorically look like reality, with increased speeds at longer distances, but it would require the Earth to be the center of such a universe. Fourth is the dark energy model : objects don’t have proper velocity, space is expanding in between them. Then come my question : is gravitational redshift (cases five and six) correctly illustrated in the animation ?
To my understanding, if all the time borders of our visible universe were putting on mass and being dilated we would experience stronger redshift on distant objects than on close ones, but it has geocentric implications. Since gravitational redshift is not Doppler-like, it has nothing to see with length or velocity, but is instead related to a scalar transition, then two cases are identical: all visible universe ends put on mass, or symmetrically  just our local galactic area is losing mass. Blue shift would be observed if all visible universe ends were losing mass and contracting, or if our area was gaining mass and dilating. Am I right?
edit: to clarify the question, considering Andromeda and the Milky Way getting closer on one side, and Fermi Bubbles growing/getting away from the Milky Way on the other, which one induces redshift and which one induces blueshift on our vision of the rest of the universe ?

I don't understand your question. Are we living in a gravity well? Yes. Does that cause a blueshift? Yes. What does this have to do with the mass loss? Gravitationally "bound" systems are always unstable. They are always losing mass in the long run.
